# Chrome CSS Display:table-cell issue when breaking apart - responsive design

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

I have created this basic fiddle to show you what is happening:

http://jsfiddle.net/wf_4/7AJL4/

I have created a responsive table where the columns are broken apart and joined back together again on the click of a button. After testing in IE, FF & Chrome I have an issue in Chrome where the second row does not jump back into the first row once the breaker is removed.

Is this just a bug in Chrome or am I missing something?

This is the code I am using:

HTML:

```
<div id="btn_001" class="button">Break Apart</div>
<div id="btn_002" class="button">Join Together</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div class="breakHere">text</div>

    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div > div {
    background-color:#ff0000;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    display:table-cell;
    border:2px solid #fff;
}

.lineBreaker {
    display:block !important;
    height:1px;
}
.button {
    width:120px;
    background-color:#0000ff;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
$("#btn_001").click(function () {
    $("<div class='lineBreaker'></div>").insertAfter('.breakHere');
});

$("#btn_002").click(function () {
    $(".lineBreaker").remove();
});
```

Comment: it is working at my side on chrome browser..

Comment: So far I have only tested Chrome 35 @BhushanKawadkar Maybe you are using an older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the parent is a table so the cells expand to fill it. Give the table-cell container an id of `parent` and then try the following jQuery:

```
$("#btn_001").click(function () {   
    $("<div class='lineBreaker'></div>").insertAfter('.breakHere');
    $('#parent').css('display', 'block');
});

$("#btn_002").click(function () {
    $(".lineBreaker").remove();
    $('#parent').css('display', 'table');
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/7AJL4/1/)

Comment: I had tried each of those properties on the "parent" but neither had worked. I'd not considered switching it each time - Works as I expected. Thank you.